Pydantic function: assemble_cors_origins does not work as intented
I am having some problems with CORS in local deployment using Pydantic and FastAPI. It's a weird problem, because on how I import the domains on which I allow CORS, it works or not.
ERROR OBTAINED

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.

When allowing all possible domains to be able requesting I don't have any problem:
if settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS:

    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=["*"],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )

The following code is the one I am currently using, and after doing debug I know that everything seems to be fine. And it works.
BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS = ast.literal_eval(os.getenv("BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS", "[]"))

if settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS:
    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )

The problem is when I do the following, that is the way I am requested to do it:
if settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS:
    BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS =[str(origin) for origin in settings.BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS]

    app.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS,
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )

where the variable settings is located in the config.py file and has the following in-built function:
# BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS is a JSON-formatted list of origins
# e.g: '["http://localhost", "http://localhost:4200", "http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:8080"]'
BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS: List[AnyHttpUrl]
@field_validator("BACKEND_CORS_ORIGINS", mode="before")
@classmethod
def assemble_cors_origins(cls, value: Union[str, List[str]]) -> Union[List[str], str]:
    backend_cors_origins = None
    if isinstance(value, str) and not value.startswith("["):
    backend_cors_origins = [i.strip() for i in value.split(",")]
    elif isinstance(value, (list, str)):
        backend_cors_origins = value
    if backend_cors_origins:
        return backend_cors_origins
    raise ValueError(value)

I have tried to do debug here, and the output list seems to be correct. That's why I don't understand what is happening.
